# Setting index values to pd.DataFrame `index` argument removes data from columns

Tags: python, pandas

When I create new DataFrame with custom index values it replaces data from columns with NaN/NaT values.

I've tried assigning pd.Index as an `index` argument as well, and result was the same.

```py
pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "date": pd.Series([datetime(2000, 1, 2)]),
        "duration": pd.Series([datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 5)]),
    }
    index = [1] 
    )
```

Instead of:

```
    date    duration
1   2000-01-02  1970-01-01 00:05:00
```

I receive:

```
    date    duration
1   NaT NaT
```

Is it a bug?

I use pandas 0.25.0

Comment: The indexes in your dataframe constructor and in your series have to match. `pd.Series` yields default indexes starting at 0, and you passed `[1]` as argument in your `pd.DataFrame`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `Series` from `DataFrame` constructor, because their default index is `0`, so different like `index of DataFrame`, so returned missing values (indices have to match):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "date": [datetime(2000, 1, 2)],
        "duration": [datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 5)],
    },
    index = [1] 
    )

print (df)
        date            duration
1 2000-01-02 1970-01-01 00:05:00
```

**Detail**:

```
print (pd.Series([datetime(2000, 1, 2)]))
0   2000-01-02
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

So if need `Series`, there is necessary set index to `1` too:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "date": pd.Series([datetime(2000, 1, 2)], index = [1]),
        "duration": pd.Series([datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 5)],index = [1]),
    },
    index = [1] 
    )
```

Or remove in `DataFrame` for default `0` index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "date": pd.Series([datetime(2000, 1, 2)]),
        "duration": pd.Series([datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 5)]),
    },
    )

print (df)
        date            duration
0 2000-01-02 1970-01-01 00:05:00
```